# what MatOfMatch object is needed for?

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I wrote the below code to get a the feeling about the feature detection.
 but what i could not understand is, why do we need `MatOfMatch` object, what it is needed for?

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat img_0 = Highgui.imread(PATH_0);
    Mat img_0_rev = Highgui.imread(PATH_1);
    Mat img_output = new Mat();

    FeatureDetector fDetect = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);

    MatOfKeyPoint mKeyPoints_0 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    fDetect.detect(img_0, mKeyPoints_0);
    System.out.println("mKeyPoint_0: " + mKeyPoints_0.size());

    MatOfKeyPoint mKeyPoints_1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    fDetect.detect(img_0_rev, mKeyPoints_1);
    System.out.println("mKeyPoint_1: " + mKeyPoints_1.size());

    MatOfDMatch mDMatch = new MatOfDMatch();

    //Features2d.drawKeypoints(mKeyPoints_0, mKeyPoints_0, outImage, Scalar color, Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    Features2d.drawMatches(img_0, mKeyPoints_0, img_0_rev, mKeyPoints_1, mDMatch, img_output);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with the Java API but I imagine the process is similar in any language.

If you just want to **detect** features (keypoints) then you don't need to use matches.

But, if you want to **match** features between two images then there's a little more to do.

The general steps are as follows:

1. Detect features (keypoints) on your images using a feature detector.
2. Pull out descriptors of your keypoints using a descriptor extractor.
3. Compare descriptors to create matches (DMatch) using a descriptor matcher.
4. Sort out your best matches and draw them.

Comment: thanks i followed these steps and i got it, but still there are many features falsely matched to others, and i do not know how to correct it...can you please offer any suggestions.thanks...my question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536493/how-to-get-correctly-matched-features