# how to get correctly matched features

Tags: java, opencv

I am making features detection in two different images, and the resultant image from the Descriptors Matcher contains features that do not belong to each other as see in the `img_1` below.

The steps I followed are as follows:

1. Features detection using SIFT algorithm. and this step yields MatOdKeyPoint object for each image, which means
   MatKeyPts_1 and MatKeyPts_2
2. Descriptors extractor using SURF algorithm.
3. Descriptors matching using BRUTFORCE algorithm. the code of this step is posted below, and the descriptor extractor of the `query_img` and the `train_img` were used as input in this step. I am also using my own classes that I created to control and maintain this process.

The problem is, the result from step 3 is the image posted below `img_1`, which has completely non-similar features linked to eah others, i expected to see,for an example, the specific region of the hand(img_1, right) is linked to the similar feature in the hand in the (img_1,left), but as you see i got mixed and unrelated features.

My question is how to get correct features matching using SIFT and SURF as features detectors and descriptor extractor respectively?

```
private static void descriptorMatcher() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MatOfDMatch matDMatch = new MatOfDMatch();//empty MatOfDmatch object
    dm.match(matFactory.getComputedDescExtMatAt(0), matFactory.getComputedDescExtMatAt(1), matDMatch);//descriptor extractor of the query and the train image are used as parameters 
    matFactory.addRawMatchesMatDMatch(matDMatch);

    /*writing the raw MatDMatches*/
    Mat outImg = new Mat();
    Features2d.drawMatches(matFactory.getMatAt(0), matFactory.getMatKeyPtsAt(0), matFactory.getMatAt(1), matFactory.getMatKeyPtsAt(1), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(matFactory.getRawMatchesMatDMatchList()), 
            outImg);
    matFactory.addRawMatchedImage(outImg);
    MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath(SystemConstants.RAW_MATCHED_IMAGE), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(matFactory.getRawMatchedImageList()));//this produce img_2 below posted

    /*getting the top 10 shortest distance*/
    List<DMatch> dMtchList = matDMatch.toList();
    List<DMatch> goodDMatchList = MatFactory.getTopGoodMatches(dMtchList, 0, 10);//this method sort the dMatchList ascendingly and picks onlt the top 10 distances and assign these values to goodDMatchList

    /*converting the goo DMatches to MatOfDMatches*/
    MatOfDMatch goodMatDMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
    goodMatDMatches.fromList(goodDMatchList);
    matFactory.addGoodMatchMatDMatch(goodMatDMatches);

    /*drawing the good matches and writing the good matches images*/
    Features2d.drawMatches(matFactory.getMatAt(0), matFactory.getMatKeyPtsAt(0), matFactory.getMatAt(1), matFactory.getMatKeyPtsAt(1), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(matFactory.getGoodMatchMatDMatchList()), 
            outImg);
    MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath(SystemConstants.GOOD_MATCHED_IMAGE), outImg);// this produce img_1 below posted
}
```

Img_1[image]

Comment: Your two images are quite different so I'm not sure if you'll be able to match a whole lot, you could try different feature detectors/extractors or using a different matching technique (KNN) and filtering the returned matches. There's also the option of taking a machine learning approach for face recognition.

Comment: @user3510227 thanks for ur comment. actually i have used ORB as well, and it matches the features pretty well. but as far as i read, ORB is intended to works with gray scale image, am i mistaken? one more point please, i am just confused about the returned matches from the .match(..,..,..) method.I just take these matches and ascendingly sorth them and pick the top 10,30 or whatever suits me, is this way correct? or i should use thresholding as most of the ppl involved in this matter do? please advidce

Comment: I believe ORB uses 8-bit Grayscale images, you can easily convert your images through OpenCV if needed though. There are lots of techniques you can try for filtering matches out, but if the matches are weak to begin with you won't see much improvement.